# Comparing two dates with sql/rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am quite confused about comparing these dates. I have a line of code which is:

`.where('invoices.invoice_status >= 100 AND invoices.shipping_mode = -1 AND invoices.archived_at IS NULL AND invoices.written_off_at IS NULL AND invoices.signup IS FALSE AND invoices.send_at >= ?', since_time)`

send_at is `Thu, 12 Jul 2018 17:18:53 CEST +02:00`

since_time is `2018-07-12T17:12:37.673+02:00`

I believe my code is faulty and won't work because these datetimes look different. Am I correct?

UPDATE

```
Hubspot::Setting Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "hubspot_settings".* FROM "hubspot_settings" WHERE "hubspot_settings"."company_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "data_privacy_downloads" WHERE "data_privacy_downloads"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_company_links" ON "users"."id" = "user_company_links"."user_id" WHERE "user_company_links"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.6ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.6ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.6ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.6ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (1.8ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-30')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("invoices"."actual_total") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoice_status >= 100 AND archived_at IS NULL and is_duplicate IS NOT TRUE) AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31') AND ("invoices"."invoice_date" BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-31')  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |   EmailSubscription Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "email_subscriptions".* FROM "email_subscriptions" WHERE "email_subscriptions"."company_id" = $1  ORDER BY email_subscriptions.email_type asc, lower(email_subscriptions.email) asc  [["company_id", 10]]
19:09:04 log.1       |    (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."company_id" = $1 AND (invoices.archived_at IS NULL AND invoices.signup IS FALSE AND invoices.send_at IS NOT NULL AND invoices.written_off_at IS NULL AND invoices.send_at >= DATE('2018-07-27') AND DATE(invoices.send_at) <= '2018-07-31 21:59:59.999999')  [["company_id", 10]]
```

Comment: did you try it?  different databases will cast differently.  what db are you on?

Comment: @Anthony if I remove the date, it returns the object so I know the problem is to do with the dates.

Comment: Share the log message for the SQL it produces

Comment: Step 1 for debugging Rails SQL issues: Look at the SQL that is being generated. What SQL is being generated?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like you might want to refactor to use a state machine when you have the time. I think it might be comparing `invoices.send_at` to a string try changing the last part of your where query to `invoices.send_at >= ?', 'DATE('+since_time+')'`

Comment: Seems like we're missing something here... the SQL log you posted shows `invoices.send_at >= DATE('2018-07-27') AND DATE(invoices.send_at) <= '2018-07-31 21:59:59.999999')` but there is nothing in your query that should be casting to `DATE`, either for `since_time` or for `invoices.send_at`.

Comment: "I believe my code is faulty and won't work because these datetimes look different. Am I correct?"
Unlikely. Rails formats data from the db when it outputs. As long as `send_at` is a datetime type column it should work. Ref: https://gist.github.com/supremebeing7/4f25307bfa48cef93d22c54152118e2f

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to parse the Dates since they are not in the same format:

```
.where('invoices.invoice_status >= 100 AND invoices.shipping_mode = -1 AND invoices.archived_at IS NULL AND invoices.written_off_at IS NULL AND invoices.signup IS FALSE AND DATE(invoices.send_at) >= ?', DATE(since_time))
```